# The vector space of square-integrable complex functions and the triangle inequality squared

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

In proving that the square-integrable functions $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ can be made into a complex vector space, my book endeavors to prove that the space is closed under superposition. Thus, it writes
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\varphi(x) + \alpha \psi(x)|^2 \, dx \leq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\varphi(x)|^2 \, dx + |\alpha^2|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\psi(x)|^2 \, dx < \infty, $$
but I can't for the life of me understand what is going on in this second step. I imagined that we should have used the triangle inequality,
$$|\varphi(x) + \alpha \psi(x)|^2 \leq |\varphi(x)|^2 + |\alpha|^2| \psi(x)|^2 + 2|\varphi(x)||\alpha|| \psi(x)|,$$
but of course this last term on the RHS does not appear above.

What is going on? Is there some basic complex analysis that I don't know which is being used here?

Comment: Which book is it by the way?

Comment: Szekeres, A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics, page 135. @BrunoB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inequality, as written, is wrong (just check for $\psi=\varphi$). I think the author is just confused because the map $\lVert f\rVert_2= \sqrt{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert f(x)\rvert^2\,dx}$ is subadditive. But here we are considering its square!

What should be done is, as you suggest, $$\lVert \varphi+\alpha\psi\rVert_2^2\le \lVert \varphi\rVert_2^2+\lvert\alpha\rvert^2\lVert\psi \rVert_2^2+2\lvert\alpha\rvert\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert \varphi(x)\psi(x)\rvert\,dx\\\le\lVert \varphi\rVert_2^2+\lvert\alpha\rvert^2\lVert\psi \rVert_2^2 +2\alpha(\lVert\psi \rVert_2\lVert\varphi \rVert_2)$$

The last inequality being Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: The last inequality (this particular case of CS) is what escaped me. I suppose one needs to use some basic complex analysis to prove this?

Comment: @EE18 I don't know what the economy of your book is: you can go Cauchy-Schwarz, you can go $\lvert ab\rvert\le \frac12(\lvert a\rvert^2+\lvert b\rvert^2)$, as long as you end up with a finite quantity.

Comment: I don't think I can yet use CS as I haven't even defined any inner product on this space yet. At any rate, your latter suggestion was perfect for me. I've accepted but, if possible, can you confirm how that argument would go? I thought something like $ 0 \leq |a-b|^2 = |a|^2 + |b|^2 -2Re(ab^*) \geq |a|^2 + |b|^2 -2|ab^*| = |a|^2 + |b|^2 -2|ab|$ but this obviously gets me nowhere.

Comment: @EE18 Go $$\lvert \varphi+\alpha\psi\rvert^2\le \lvert \varphi\rvert^2+\lvert\alpha\rvert^2\lvert\psi\rvert^2+2\lvert\alpha\rvert\lvert\psi\rvert\lvert\varphi\rvert \le \lvert \varphi\rvert^2+\lvert\alpha\rvert^2\lvert\psi\rvert^2+2\lvert\alpha\rvert\left(\frac{\lvert \varphi\rvert^2+\lvert\psi\rvert^2}2\right)$$ and integrate

Comment: Yes I did that, but I am saying I can't seem to prove $\lvert ab\rvert\le \frac12(\lvert a\rvert^2+\lvert b\rvert^2)$ in the first place. Would it be possible to stitch up my attempt there?

Comment: @EE18 You have $(|a| - |b|)^2 = |a|^2 + |b|^2 - 2|ab| \geq 0$.

Comment: Oy, nice and easy! Thanks @BrunoB